# Goalseek over range of values not running

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my code. When I hit run, nothing happens.

Whats wrong?

I'm basically changing variables over a range G53:N53 and F54:F64 and looping it to change C54 to 0 while changing C59, and then I'm pasting it around the matrix G54:N64.

But its not running!

```
Private Sub CheckGoalSeek()

 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

   For i = 54 To 64
    For j = 7 To 14
       Cells(60, 3).Value = Cells(53, j).Value
       Cells(61, 3).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value
       Range("C54").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C59")
       Cells(59, 3).Copy
       Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next j
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Should Range(C59) be Range("C59") ?  Ditto C54

Comment: `Range(C54).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range(C59)` should definitely be `Range("C54").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C59")` but I don't know whether there are other errors.  (And I'm surprised that "nothing happens" - I would have expected that to throw an error when it ran.)  Note:  You should include `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module - that would have highlighted that error.

Comment: whooops! i changed it, but still nothing is happening? :(

Comment: oh waitttt so somehow it worked but i had to open a new excel workbook! which is queer.